# How to re-download Vault Credentials

Tags: azure-backup-vault

One of my backups has failed because seemingly the pass phase is corrupted.
I am attempting to re-register the server (I do not know if this will fix the problem but I do know that in this process the pass phrase is entered) and so need to re-download the Vault Credentials.

In the old Azure portal the download of the Vault Credentials link was right there as soon as you went to the particular vault.

In the new Azure portal I cannot find it anywhere. I have looked and looked and Googled and Googled.

I get the feeling that one has to start the whole backup setup again for the server in order to get the credentials via Getting Started > Backup.

So I am in vault that the server backs up to and I go to Getting Started > Backup and follow the steps and then I end up with a list of servers that I need to choose from but my server is not there because it says "VMs in same region as vault and not protected by another vault are shown....".

Anyway I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path to download the vault credential file: Home>Recovery Services vaults>Select your recovery services vault>Properties>Backup credentials

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Vikranth.

I would like to add that one needs to check the box (Already using the ...) before the Download button is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

OK I fixed my problem but I did not resolve the "How to re-download Vault Credentials".

In the Azure Backup app on the server I went to Actions > Change Properties and re-entered the pass phrase and tried to save it.

I got a message that nothing was saved because the pass phrase had not changed.

So how the heck did it know that if my initial problem was that the pass phrase was corrupted???

I chanced my luck and tried a "Backup Now" and lo and behold it worked.

GO FIGURE AND THANK YOU TEAM AT MS FOR YET ANOTHER CONUNDRUM I HAD TO SOLVE WITH SMOKE AND MIRRORS.

Don't get me started...